# Unable to change +CSCS value

Tags: at-command

I am using a SIM800L module and I am trying to make it send an SMS. When I type the command `AT+CSCS`? it gives the output `+CSCS="IRA"`. I want to change this to `"GSM"`. When I try changing it using `AT+CSCS = "GSM"` and then try `AT+CSCS`? again, it gives `+CSCS="IRA"`.

I have tried the command `AT+CSCS = "GSM"`

```
AT

AT+CSCS?

AT+CSCS = "GSM"

AT+CSCS
```

`AT` gives `OK` 
`AT+CSCS?` gives "`IRA`" 
`AT+CSCS = "GSM"` returns OK
`AT+CSCS?` returns `IRA` 
For some reason, when I try to change `+CSCS` to "`GSM`" it doesn't work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: What does `AT+CSCS=?` report?

Comment: @hlovdal AT+CSCS=? gives +CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2","HEX","PCCP","PCDN","8859-1")

Comment: Does switching to any of the other character sets work? (Notice that after switching to UCS-2 you need to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349341/23118](switch back using a UCS-2 string)).

Comment: @hlovdal No. I am not able to write to the SIM