# Where is the error for sending sms from gsm in rasberry?

Tags: python, gsm, at-command

When i run this python code to send sms from gsm, I recive a message

> content not supported

```
import serial
import time 

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600) 
time.sleep(1) 
ser.write('ATE0\r') 
time.sleep(1) 
ser.write('ATZ\r') 
time.sleep(1) 
ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r') 
time.sleep(1) 
ser.write('AT+CMGS= "+989337282702" \r') 
time.sleep(1) 
ser.write('hi \r')
time.sleep(1) 
ser.write(chr(26)) 
time.sleep(1)

print 'sent successfully'
```

Comment: Please paste the complete error message.

Comment: There is not error that i see .just i recived message in mobile with content <<content not supported>>

Comment: Ah, ok. On the sending or receiving cell phone? Them I am not sure if you will find help here. I googled for GSM and "content not supported" and there are several results. Could you try `ser.write('hi')` instead of `ser.write('hi \r')`? This code looks slightly different `"AT+CMGS=\"+ZZXXXXXXXXXX\"\r"` https://mechatrofice.com/arduino/gsm/send-sms

Comment: I tried but the soulotion is not  this

Comment: Does "content not supported" appear on the sending or receiving phone?

Comment: No! No! No! You should [never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, ever use sleep like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064206/23118). You MUST **read** and **parse** the responses given back by the modem, otherwise you will [abort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389034/23118) the commands.

Comment: See also the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118).

Comment: @Joe appears on sending and instaed of recive message for user ,recive  "content not sopported"

Comment: @hlovdal tnx man but i checked also whit any sleep but still when i send mesaage from gms to phone i have this problem

Comment: Please update the question with the new code that does not use sleep. Does the modem actually support text mode? Have you tried sending a sms to another number? Using another sim card? Another phone?

Comment: @hlovdal i tried to send to other number other phone but still it is that

Comment: @hlovdal help please

Comment: If you want people to help you, then you should not make yourself sound like a [help vampyre](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: @hlovdal tnx but what i do ?