# AT+CMGL="ALL" return OK only

Tags: c#, at-command

I have 1 gsm 32 port with name is xr21v1414 USB UART

I have tested another AT COMMAND which works fine like

AT 
USSD

but if i use COMMAND :

```
  serialPort.WriteLine("AT" + System.Environment.NewLine);
  Thread.Sleep(200);
  serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);
  Thread.Sleep(200);
  serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"" + System.Environment.NewLine);
  Thread.Sleep(200);
```

responded with

```
serialPort.ReadExisting();
```

is empty (OK only)

```
AT

OK
AT+CMGF=1

OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
OK
```

But if I switch to another gsm, Command work fine. I have list SMS.

This is my setting :

```
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
            serialPort.PortName = m.ToString();
            serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 20000;
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = 20000;
            serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 1024;
            serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
```

How could i resolve the problem ,please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure that the `OK` response you get is because you have [aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389034/23118) the current command line by using `Thread.Sleep(200)` instead of [**reading** and **parsing**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) the response you get back from the modem, waiting for the *Final Result Code* before sending the next command.

The first linked answer above is to a question whose code which is slightly worse because it does not even have a sleep, but even having one is utterly wrong. Just as you would not write a HTTP client that ignores the responses a HTTP server send it, you should not write a AT command program that ignores the responses the modems sends it.

TL;DR You **MUST** change your code to **read** and **parse** every single response line that the modem sends you, waiting for the Final Result Code before sending the next command. See the linked answers for more details.